# Laravel 4 Common Assets

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am attempting to transition from CodeIgniter to Laravel for a new application. I've done something similar to the following in CodeIgniter, but it isn't working as I expect in Laravel. I have the following code as my BaseController in Laravel 4:

```
class BaseController extends Controller {
    private $css_files = array('bootstrap3.min.css');
    private $js_files  = array();

    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout)
                        ->with('css_files',$this->get_css())
                        ->with('js_files',$this->get_js());
        }
    }

    private function get_css(){
        return $this->css_files;
    }

    public function add_css($css_file){
        $this->css_files[] = $css_file;
    }

    private function get_js(){
        return $this->js_files;
    }

    public function add_js($js_file){
        $this->js_files[] = $js_file;
    }

}
```

And I'm trying to be able to add js and css assets dynamically :

```
class LoginController extends BaseController {  
    protected $layout    = 'layouts.main';

    public function index(){
        $this->add_css('login.css');

        $this->layout->content = View::make('auth.login');
    }
}
```

View Code :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>APP NAME</title>
    @foreach( $css_files as $css )
        {{ HTML::style("css/{$css}") }}
    @endforeach
</head>
```

If I make the accessor methods public and call them from the LoginController, they show the added css files as expected.

 
If I add the login.css file name into the css files array directly, as the bootstrap css is, it works as expected.

What am I doing wrong that's causing the css files to not show up from the BaseController to the LoginController? Am I going about it the wrong way? Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 0):

setupLayout() will be called before your LoginController.
As such, the reference to $this->css_files will only have the bootstrap CSS file in it.

To (hackily) get around this, pass the css and js arrays by reference, like so:

```
$this->layout = View::make($this->layout)
    ->with('css_files', &$this->css_files) 
     ->with('js_files', &$this->js_files);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info about the process calling order, but when I tried that, I got the following error : syntax error, unexpected '&'

Comment: Apologies, I have edited my answer. The syntax error was due to not being able to return a reference.